# Cannot unit test in Kotlin (ExecutionException, Aapt2Exception)

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

A simple test...

```
import org.junit.Test

class KotlinUnitTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        assert(true)
    }
}
```

... results in the following...

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugUnitTest]
Information:Kotlin: Kotlin JPS plugin is disabled
Information:Module "app" was fully rebuilt due to project configuration/dependencies changes
Information:06/12/2017 5:08 PM - Compilation completed with 3 errors and 0 warnings in 19s 962ms
Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Gradle: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to **gradle.properties** (or also **gradle-wrapper.properties**) made Android Studio halt indefinitely every time I ran the test.

This is weird because I'm able to...

- Run my production app (filled with Kotlin files)
- Unit test in Java

But, for whatever reason, I can't test in Kotlin

Comment: show gradle dependencies please

Answer (score 4):

I've had similar problems with meaningless AAPT2 errors while running kotlin tests. The source of the problem is in Android Studio generating wrong Run Configuration for tests in Kotlin. I'm not sure what causes this bug because it looks it's not happening to everyone.

Running unit tests via command line worked without problems.

Creating test configuration by hand resolved the issue:
[image: create configuration manually]

But still if I try to run the test by clicking the *side note* button I got the compilation error.
[image: run test button]

BTW: If you try to edit the generated configuration you are out of luck because that configuration isn't listed in the configurations list at all.

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem. for a simple test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class)
class MainActivityTest {
    private lateinit var activityController: ActivityController<MainActivity>

    @Before
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun setUp() {
        activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java)

        activityController.create().start().resume()

    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun testNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(activityController.get())
    }

}
```

Update to latest Kotlin version to 1.1.60 and Gradle to 3.0.1 solve it.

Comment: But latest version of Kotlin is 1.2.0

Comment: @OsipXD Interesting, Android Studio told me to change to 1.1.60.

Comment: may be because you've not updated Kotlin plugin in AS?

Comment: That make sense, thanks for the tip. Anyway, 1.1.60 works for me.

Comment: @HarryHan making kotlin version to 1.1.60 does not resolve the issue for me, I am still getting the below error, Can you please provide any idea/solution on this:

Comment: Error:Gradle: failed to create directory 'D:\...'.
Error:Gradle: failed processing manifest.
Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Gradle: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Gradle: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processInstallStagingDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

Comment: @Devavrata, show  show gradle dependencies and gradle errors

Comment: @Devavrata Do you find solution for issue ? I am facing same for espresso test with kotlin `1.2.60` version and gradle version is `3.0.1`